# How would I define types for a Blob with JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, blob, jsdoc

I need to create a blob to test a file upload function. I'd like to annotate it in vscode but I keep getting the following error: `Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type '{ lastModifiedDate: Date; name: string; }': lastModifiedDate, name ts(2739)`

This is what I have so far:

```
/** @type {{lastModifiedDate: Date, name:string}} */

const blob = new Blob([range(1024)], { type: 'image/png' });

blob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
blob.name = name;
```

It works in that it shows be the type declarations but it still throws the error.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't want a `Blob` here, you want a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Comment: Sure, the same question applies though.

Comment: Have you found one yet?